# Passing HTML into TemplateURL using directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get the HTML inside the directive tag into the template file and render it on the screen

HTML

```
<insert-test-tab><b>Put this text in the template test.html</b></insert-test-tab>
```

script.js

```
directive('insertTestTab', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    },
    templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
      return 'test.html'
    },
  }
}
```

test.html

```
<div>
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
  <p>[[I want to get that HTML inside <insert-test-tab> here]]</p>
</div>
```

Desired output

```
<div>
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
  <b>Put this text in the template test.html</b>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive definition:

```
  directive('insertTestTab', function() {   
    return {
   replace: true,
   transclude: true,
   link: function (scope, element, attr) {

    }, templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
      return 'test.html'
    },   
 } 
}
```

test.html:

```
<div>
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
  <p><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using directive tranclude feature.

So your directive definition should be as follows :

```
directive('insertTestTab', function() {   return {
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        }, templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
          return 'test.html'
        },   
    } 
}
```

And test.html should::

```
<div>
  <p>bla bla bla</p>
  <p><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></p>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you(Ref:: https://codepen.io/pankajbadukale/pen/aVbGaM)

Comment: I get this error:
Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element: <ng-transclude>

Do you know why?

Comment: I think its because I have the whole thing inside another directive and is not liking it. Thanks any ways.